# Bash - print first line of textfile (csv) bold

Tags: text-processing, sed, colors, csv, text-formatting

I have a text (csv) file like this:

```
Date:;Time:;Value:;
20181202;112044;38274658392;
20181207;121356;94843726283;
20181221;221012;93938272189;
20181230;071234;93736473783;
20190107;011022;27339393022;
20190112;042346;84739298321;
```

I use `column -s';' -t file` to get a nicely formatted output:

```
Date:     Time:   Value:
20181202  112044  38274658392
20181207  121356  94843726283
20181221  221012  93938272189
20181230  071234  93736473783
20190107  011022  27339393022
20190112  042346  84739298321
```

Is there a simple way to print the first line of the text file with bold letters?

I know one can use `tput` with bash:

```
bold=$(tput bold)
reset=$(tput sgr0)
```

How can I add this to the beginning and the end of the first line?
I'm thinking of `sed` at the moment...

Comment: Something like `sed "1s/\(.*\)/$bold\1$reset/"` ?

Comment: @StephenHarris, yea this one is working, THX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could use `awk` for this:

```
column -s\; -t file | awk -v bld=$(tput bold) -v rst=$(tput sgr0) 'NR == 1{$0 = bld$0rst} 1'
```

This will make the first line of the column output bold

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `sed` and ANSI escapes using the regex from Stephen Harris:

```
<file sed "1s/\(.*\)/\x1b[1m\1\x1b[0m/" | column -s\; -t
```

where `\x1b` is the hexadecimal value of octal `\033` which is used in ANSI escapes like

```
printf '\033[1m%s\033[0m\n' hello
# or
printf '\x1b[1m%s\x1b[0m\n' world
```